# What is the best javascript templating engine for scalability, performance, and dealing with complex html graphs?

Tags: javascript, templates

Currently, what is the most widely used javascript templating engine that is very scalable, performance in the popular web browsers (even IE6-8) and can easily deal with very complex HTML graphs and decisional presentational logic?

EDIT: What I mean about decisional presentation logic is creating content using logic and not just a way to put in variable placeholders.

Comment: What is "decisional presentational logic"? How scalable is "scalable"? Which version(s) of IE?

Comment: Curious about the definition of 'complex HTML graphs' -- how complex is complex, and are you looking for DOM manipulation or something of the like? And what sort of features are you looking for in order to make it easy to deal with these structures?

Answer (score 1):

http://beebole.com/pure/ claims to be

> Simple and ultra-fast ...

Comment: How widely-used is it?  Can it deal with very complex HTML graphs and decisional presentational logic?

Comment: MYYN, did you try it to say that? Tx for spreading the word :)

Comment: @Pointy, unlike many template engines, PURE takes an existing HTML as template without funny tags, and changes only what needs to be, without stringify/eval everything.

Comment: @Mic. No I haven't tried it, just copied it from your site.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js is both robust and widely used, it is a good choice.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: Backbone.js also provides models, and it effects templates through the use of views. One nice thing about Backbone.js is that, if you update the content of a model, the view will change automatically. So your data and presentation are separate but tieghtly linked.

Comment: Backbone, while epic in every respect, does not have its own template engine. It uses Underscore.js, which does have a simple templating feature

Answer (score 0):

[doT.js](http://olado.github.com/doT/) is apparently [lightning](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/103) [fast](http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/253) (those stunningly long bars in the graphs are doT). As for your 'most widely used' criterion, I doubt it'd fall into that category, but that doesn't mean it's a bad solution! It's got [134 watchers](https://github.com/olado/doT/watchers) and [8 forks](https://github.com/olado/doT/network) on GitHub, though, so it does seem to have some traffic. Actively maintained... decisional presentation support through the inclusion of JavaScript statements... works in node.js and the browser (I just tested it in IE6; it works great). I'm not quite sure what the definition of 'complex HTML graphs' is, but I presume that by your use of the word 'graphs', you're talking about having a DOM tree that you can manipulate with this engine. Don't think this would be that great for you, although you can use nested loop statements in a template.

I've just started using it, and it's quite a simple engine, but that's one of the reasons it's so fast!

Answer (score 0):

Use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), Its simple and straightforward.
For performance statistics see [this](http://jsperf.com/javascript-template-engine-compare/20)

Regards!